# Equal Columns JS ignoring content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the code below, to target some portfolio boxes and make them equal heights. Usually I have no problem with this code but for some reason, it sets the height as if there is no content inside it. Almost like it's ignoring any content inside.

I have looked at the CSS and cannot see anything effecting the height, other than the JS dictating the column height.

Here is the code ([live site](http://www.cosustainconsulting.com/projects/)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        function equalHeights(selector) {
            var maxHeight = 0;
            function calcEqualHeight() {
                var el = $(this);
                maxHeight = el.height() > maxHeight ? el.height() : maxHeight;
            }
            selector.each(calcEqualHeight).height(maxHeight);
        }

        equalHeights($('.ffb-portfolio-content-2'));
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Without HTML code here I can't know what this function is doing. But from seeing your live site, I suppose you want the white background bellow the pictures to have the height of the content.

Analyzing your HTML I've reached the conclusion you can do that using this: `$(".ffb-portfolio-content-2").height($(".ffb-title-2-1").height())` Assuming 'ffb-title-2-1' is the content and 'fbb-portfolio-content-2' is the white background div.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your script is running before the page is completely rendered.  I was able to force the correct behaviour by running `$('.ffb-portfolio-content-2').attr("style", null)` to undo the incorrect behaviour, then running your script again from the console.

A solution to this would simply be to delay your script until the page has fully loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function equalHeights(selector) {
        var maxHeight = 0;
        function calcEqualHeight() {
            var el = $(this);
            maxHeight = el.height() > maxHeight ? el.height() : maxHeight;
        }
        selector.each(calcEqualHeight).height(maxHeight);
    }

    equalHeights($('.ffb-portfolio-content-2'));
});
```

Comment: Running the script from console works becasue images have already been loaded. $(document).ready() will not wait for images to load in the browser. So the best thing to do is run your function call on $(window).load()

Comment: @hellojebus Surely the fault here is to do with the text in the `div`s overflowing onto multiple lines, not in the constant-height images?

Comment: True dat. You're right, I didn't see link to the site.

Answer (score 0):

This will run when the DOM is ready, not necessarily when all the resources have loaded such as images.

If you happen to have images in those columns, this is likely the culprit. Try wrapping your equalHeights call within $(window).load() as below:

```
(function() {
    function equalHeights(selector) {
        var maxHeight = 0;
        function calcEqualHeight() {
            var el = $(this);
            maxHeight = el.height() > maxHeight ? el.height() : maxHeight;
        }
        selector.each(calcEqualHeight).height(maxHeight);
    }

    //run equalHeights once everything is loaded
    $(window).load(function(){
        equalHeights($('.ffb-portfolio-content-2'));
    });

})();
```

Don't forget that column height will also vary if the user scales their browser...so you may want to call the function on $(window).resize() aswell.